# xctest This app has attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, xctest

I am attempting to test CoreLocation with a unit test (xctest), this failing to get past the permissions stage. I specifically get an assumed error message,
see below(*).

I am swizzling the authorizationStatus method but this not working for me.

```
[MySwizzler swizzleClass:[CLLocationManager class]
                         method:@"authorizationStatus"
                 instanceMethod:NO];

+ (CLAuthorizationStatus)override_authorizationStatus {
    return myAuthorizationStatus;
}
```

As soon as I request authorization:

```
[[self locationManager] requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
```

I get the callback:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {
```

and the status is:

```
kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted
```

My swizzled method never gets called and I get this message in my log:

(*)
"This app has attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data".

my Plist does contain this:

```
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Required</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Required</string>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

- And my TestTarget Info.plist property is set to the path of the Plist
  file.
- The Scheme Run Configuration is set to "Allow Location
  Simulation"

I am assuming I am swizzling the wrong method here and maybe some other 
problems.

Please assist.

Comment: Perhaps you should swizzle requestWhenInUseAuthorization instead.

Comment: Mike.. maybe you are right, it is so obvious :) let me try that.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you added the keys to the Test target's Info.plist instead?

Comment: Please change this into a more assertive answer or into a clarfication question in a comment. You do have the commmenting privilege you know.

Comment: I think its appropriate because this solved the problem I had. I can't really know if this is the case for them or not.

Comment: If you do not know, ask in a comment. Alternatively make an assertive though conditional answer: "Your problem might be that you have ... . In that case the solution is ...". I propose this as a phrasing to make the answer more assertive, without making an implicit assumption (those are really dangerous), but also without giving the impression of being a question which should be in a comment. You could otherwise improve the perceived helpfulness of the answer, by adding some background info or maybe some " ... because ...".

Comment: Conditional answers, as described in my previous comment, I consider mostly a tool for people below 50 rep, which you are not. But in this case the age of the question, implying that direct contact via commetns with OP is unlikely, it also is very appropriate.